# Center with Cursor property (like a crosshair)?

Tags: html, css, properties, cursor

I am making a jquery shooting/aim game and I'm not entirely sure how to make the focus of the mouse shift to the center (i.e. the crosshair property), like so (the bottom line):

```
#num {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    left: 45%;
    top: -40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10%;
    background: gray;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: url(c_hair.png), crosshair; /* HERE IS THE PROBLEM */
}
```

THANKS!!!
**UPDATE**
I am trying to make the focal point of the cursor image in the center (with the crosshair or 'precision' cursor, for example), not the default top-left (with the pointer, for example).

Comment: what do you mean? make your question clearer.

Comment: Yes, what *exactly* is your problem?

Comment: Sorry, clarified above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend told me that this is a solution, and it works

```
cursor: url(c_hair.png), auto x y
```

...would offset the cursor first by x pixels then by y pixels.

Comment: auto and other named cursors do not have x y offsets, according to the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have image why do you need crosshair?
cant you use this

`cursor: url(c_hair.png), auto;`

Comment: No, I clarified above--the focus of the mouse needs to be in the center.